# how to position the window stage in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I made a simple game and when it ends it'll display a new `Stage` with some information:

```
 public static void d(String m){
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("GAME FINISHED");
    Label label = new Label(m);
    label.setTextFill(Color.PURPLE);
    label.setFont(new Font("Cambria",14));

    Button button = new Button("Close");
    VBox vb = new VBox();
    button.setOnAction(e-> p.close());
    vb.getChildren().addAll(label,button);
    vb.setSpacing(50);
    vb.setPadding(new Insets(5,0,0,12));
    Scene scene = new Scene(v,200,300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.showAndWait();
}
```

I don't want this window to show in the middle of the screen because it hides some content of the game.
Is it possible to display a stage **not** in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [stage.setX()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setX-double-) and [stage.setY()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setY-double-) methods to set the window position manually:

```
// create and init stage
stage.setX(200);
stage.setY(200);
stage.showAndWait();
```

If you want to calculate the position based on the screen size you can use the following to get the size:

```
Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
```

If you want to use `stage.getWidth()` or `stage.getHeight()` to calculate the position you have to show the stage before:

```
stage.show();
Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() - scene.getWidth()) * 0.3;
double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() - scene.getHeight()) * 0.7;
stage.setX(x);
stage.setY(y);
```

In this case you should use `stage.show()` instead of `stage.showAndWait()`.